# Jquery form validation with multple select boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I'm having some trouble displaying form validation on multiple select boxes with this plugin:

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

The validation only appears to be working on the first select box.  If the first select box is left unselected, it will render the validation error, however, if the following select is blank, it submits the form without validation.

I've used this plugin and it's worked flawlessly with multiple text inputs but this is the first time I've tried multiple select boxes.

```
<form action="someactionhere" method="POST" class="form" id="errors">
                        <label>First Select</label><br>
                        <select id="first" class="required">
                                <option selected="" value="">Select</option>
                                <option value="first">first</option>
                                <option value="second">second</option>
                                <option value="third">third</option>
                        </select><br><br>
                        <label>Second Select</label><br>
                        <select id="second" class="required">
                                <option selected="" value="">Select</option>
                                <option value="first">first</option>
                                <option value="second">second</option>
                                <option value="third">third</option>
                        </select>
                        <button type="submit" class="button">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
<script src="/js/jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#errors").validate();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jquery.validation binds using the name attribute. Give your selects a name.

Comment: Thanks. Now I feel dumb... :)

Comment: Don't feel dumb, there really be only one reason I knew the answer to this :)